# scalatest : object scalatest is not a member of package org

Tags: scala, intellij-idea, sbt, scalatest

**EDIT** : It works if the file is in `src/test/scala/tests/` but not in `src/main/scala/mypackage/`.  Why?

I have tried solutions from topics with people having nearly the same issue but none of them work.

For details, I have this in build.sbt :

```
libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
   ...
  "org.scalatest" % "scalatest_2.10" % "2.2.1" % "test",
   ...
```

In Intellij, I have a class with:

```
import org.scalatest.{BeforeAndAfterAll, Suite}
```

with `{BeforeAndAfterAll, Suite}` in red so i guess scalatest is found

sbt package does not work either:

> object scalatest is not a member of package org [error] import
> org.scalatest. {BeforeAndAfterAll, Suite}

I have already tried this :

- sbt clean update
- restart + invalidate cache of intellij
- remove .idea/ and reimport
- libraryDependencies += "org.scalatest" % "scalatest_2.10" % "2.0" % "test" instead ogf the actual
- magical ritual on my keyboard

Nothing works

Any ideas?

Comment: Why do you want to use scalatest in src/main?

Comment: remove the % "test" from the scalatest library dependency.  As long as that's there, you won't get the required entry in the classpath during the compile phase.

Comment: Did you fix this? I am getting the same error. Any advice would be helpful.

Comment: No, sorry Srinivas

Comment: I had this very issue with Maven in IntelliJ. I invalidated caches and restarted but it didn't help. I reimported Maven and it fixed it.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

You should take a look at [sbt project structure](http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.13/docs/Directories.html#Source+code):

```
src/
  main/
    resources/
       <files to include in main jar here>
    scala/
       <main Scala sources>
    java/
       <main Java sources>
  test/
    resources
       <files to include in test jar here>
    scala/
       <test Scala sources>
    java/
       <test Java sources>
```

Your scala tests should go under `src/test/scala/`.

If you really want to use scalatest in main (and you know what you are trying to do), try this:

```
  "org.scalatest" % "scalatest_2.10" % "2.2.1",
```

In your original `build.sbt`, "test" is the configuration and it means that scalatest will only be on the test classpath and it isn’t needed by the main sources. This is generally good practice for libraries because your users don’t typically need your test dependencies to use your library ([ref](http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.13/docs/Testing.html)).

Comment: in IntelliJ switch for a second from `package view` to `project view`, then You see the misery ;) Thanks for your help!