# Why am I getting object scalatest is not a member of package org

Tags: scala

I am trying to follow the Scala [tutorial](https://github.com/scala/docs.scala-lang/blob/master/getting-started-intellij-track/testing-scala-in-intellij-with-scalatest.md) and am getting the error `object scalatest is not a member of package org`. All of the other instances of this error I can find here and on the web have the problem that the test file isn't under src/test, but that's not the case for me. I repeat, for the sake of those who keep marking this as a duplicate, **the test file is under src/test, so that is not the problem**. My build.sbt file says:

```
name := "TestExercise"

version := "0.1"

scalaVersion := "2.12.6"

libraryDependencies += "org.scalatest" %% "scalatest" % "3.0.5" % "test"
```

src/main/scala/CubeCalculator says:

```
object CubeCalculator extends App {
  def cube(x: Int) = {
    x * x * x
  }
}
```

and src/test/scala/CubeCalculatorTest says:

```
import org.scalatest.FunSuite

class CubeCalculatorTest extends FunSuite {
  test("CubeCalculator.cube") {
    assert(CubeCalculator.cube(3) === 27)
  }
}
```

(Cut-and-pasted straight from the tutorial.)

So what am I doing wrong? Why can't my project access scalatest?

Comment: Worth a shot: within the SBT shell, try `reload`, then `clean` and then `compile`.

Comment: are you getting the error in IntelliJ or by running `sbt test` in your shell? you may need to invalidate caches and restart intellij

Comment: I should correct my comment... run `test:compile` or just `test`

Comment: clear cache and try again

Comment: Possible duplicate of [scalatest : object scalatest is not a member of package org](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35488213/scalatest-object-scalatest-is-not-a-member-of-package-org)

Comment: Not a duplicate, @SundeepPidugu - as I said, I'd already ruled out an incorrect file location.

Comment: @terminally-chill that, plus a rebuild, did the trick. Thanks. I wish you'd made it an answer rather than a comment, so I could mark it as the answer.

Answer (score 1):

@terminally-chill gave the answer. I am using Intellij, and File | Invalidate caches / restart, followed by a rebuild, resolved the issue.